# Get the list of skipped tasks on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way by which we can get the list of skipped tasks from the build?

For example, I have 2 tasks that run conditionally only based on external factors. So how can I see, whether the tasks were skipped or actually ran from Azure DevOps REST API?

I need to trigger another build conditionally based on the above factor.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Build Timeline REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). If you issue the following `GET` request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline
```

where `buildId` is the ID of the build you're examining, it returns the `Timeline` object. It is essentially a collection of [`TimelineRecord` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#timelinerecord), each representing an entry in a build's timeline. You should filter out this collection to leave only those, where `"type": "Task"` and `"result": "skipped"`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was digging around Build API, and didnt check timeline. Thanks !