# Aggregate functions in WIQL query

Tags: azure-devops

I want download WIQL report using REST API. REST response doesn't give all fields but it gives a list of URLS as workItems.

To get field values I need to download each WorkItem separately. 
Any direct REST way to accomplish this in a single REST call?

Repeated REST calls gives me rate limiting or similar error. I get error 500 types after repeated GET request.

Genesis of this need is - There are no aggerate functions available likes of SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG Etc.

Comment: This helps. I have tried it. but it requires me to write more logic in my code

Comment: Yes, the rest api provides several basic option like returning IDs, get WorkItems via IDs... To achieve your requirements, we have to make a combination of these basic rest apis to get what we need.

Answer (score 0):

> REST response doesn't give all fields but it gives a list of URLS as
>   workItems.
>
> To get field values I need to download each WorkItem separately. Any
>   direct REST way to accomplish this in a single REST call?

Sorry but as I know, there's no **direct** rest api available to get WIQL report. An alternative workaround should be:

1.Use [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to return the list of WorkItem IDs and Urls (I think this is the same rest api you use).

2.Then use [Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get all the details(fields) about the requested work item ids. And here's [one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856251/10910450) which has similar needs like yours, you can use the upgraded script from **konpro11** to get list of IDs and use the IDs to get your report (with the help of second rest api).

Hope it helps :)