# Find and download all instances of a file name in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to download all files with a specific name from the master branches of all the projects in an Azure DevOps installation?

I have been tasked with documenting all of the entries in all of the appsettings.json files in our entire codebase and I would prefer to not have to go through all 300 repositories to manually download these files if I don't absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to download all files with a specific name from the
>   master branches of all the projects in an Azure DevOps installation?

This is not supported. Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops), we recommend different project(with one or more repos) for different products/sub-modules of big product. So in `Azure Devops Service` there's no such out-of-box feature to find/download files across projects.

**A possible direction:**

If those `appsettings.json` files are in root directory of your repos. You may save some time by using these two Rest APIs:

[List all repos in current organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1
```

[Get File(Download)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#download):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repositoryid}/items?scopePath=/appsettings.json&download=true&api-version=5.1
```

You can use PowerShell script to combine these two apis. The first one will list all Repositoryids in your organization, and the second one can download the `appsettings.json` from different repos via different Repositoryids. So the possible way could be run the first api once to get list of reposID(You can check this [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856251/10910450)) and then add a loop to get the files one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I was able to use the repositiories API and the trees API to get a list of everything in our installation and then download all of the various appsettings files.

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT Could you please help to resolve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407273/download-a-file-from-azure-devops-server-writes-wrong-data-to-the-file) . Your help is appreciated